# List the columns(fields) dynamically in Jquery JTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-jtable

The usual practice to list the Jquery Jtable is to specify fields along with their title and other preferences in advance.
I have a requirement that, the fields from the database may vary and they may not be the same all the time. How to dynamically show the fields in the Jtable?

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: fields: {
             id: {
              title: 'Test-Order Id',
              width: '10%',
                    key: true,
                    list: false,
                    create: false
                },
                name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '15%',
                    inputClass: 'validate[required]'
                },
            },

Comment: I want the show the fields above dynamically. I dont want to use static listing of fields as above.